# Why transforming coordinates in dimetric games?

Tags: isometric

What are the advantages of transforming coords, since you can still render isometric graphs having normal 2D coords?

[image: like this]

Answer (score 2):

You're using a transform one way or another.

With an isometric view you can pre-transform your entire scene but technically will still be using a transform if you do any scrolling. It'll be just a translation but it's still a transform.

Doing transform on the fly lets you move the camera. (Taking a page from the hitch-hiker's guide: you're actually moving the entire universe the opposite way.)

Cheers,

Edit: Having your world in 3D but projecting iso lets you rotate the camera, like many tactics games do:

[image]

Comment: Hi Stephane. That's true, but I wonder what's the advantage of translating coordinates from 2D to isometric projection, since you can still render as you want with normal 2D coords

Comment: If your world is in 3D but projecting iso you can rotate the camera. Many tactics games (Final Fantasy Tactics, La Pucelle Tactics, etc) use this. Adding photo